# MIT Open Linear Algebra Course - Block Matrix Question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

There is a practice problem for Chapter 3 of Prof. Strang's famous open linear algebra course ([problem 7 from problem set 3](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/assignments/MIT18_06S10_pset3_s10_soln.pdf)). It seems the answer is incorrect, and it reveal's something I have a question about.

$$R=\left [
\begin{array}{}
I & F \\
0 & 0
\end{array}
 \right ]$$

$R$ is the reduced row echelon form (rref) of some matrix $A$. $F$ represents the columns of free variables and could take any values. The question is to show that the rref of $R^TR$ is $R$. Here is the solution, I think the frist part is incorrect.

> [image]

That doesn't seem right to me, I think

$$R^TR=\left [
\begin{array}{}
I & F \\
F^T & F^TF
\end{array}
 \right ]$$

But, just working some examples, the second part I still find correct: $rref(R^TR)=R$. So finally to my question, how can I show this last identity, going from $R^TR$ to $rref(R^TR)=R$ with matrix algebra? So I see how the identity matrix clears out the lower left corner, $F^T$, but I am not seeing how this necessarily converts the bottom right, $F^TF$, to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $$C = \begin{bmatrix}  I & 0\\-F^T & I \end{bmatrix}.$$ Compute $CR^TR$. This is called elementary BLOCK row operations. It can also be written as a string of elementary row operations.

Comment: I would think the purpose of this is to get $CR^T=I$ however I am not seeing that, and i am not seeing that $CR^TR=R$.

Comment: Have you actually done the operation $C(R^TR)$?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I changed $C$.

Comment: OK yes now I see it, I should have known. It is actually just 1 step of elimination just like the case of a 2x2 matrix. Thanks for the help!